# Regrouping categorical values in a dataframe

Tags: r

I'm looking for a suggestion: I'm trying to re-order/group a data frame by a variable value.

For example transforming a native data frame VARS

[image: Native data frame VARS:]

into something like this:

[image: Into something like this:]

So far, I've tried `for-loops` with cbind/rbind depending on how the data is organized, aggregate, apply, etc. But there's always some wrinkle that prevents the methods from working.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to point out reading up on how to give a usefule example, along with the raw data using `dput` will go a long way to getting feedback. That said:

```
For the dataset you showed:


 A <- structure(list(Var_Typer = c("cnt", "Cont", "cnt", "cnt", "fact", 
"fact", "Char", "Char", "Cont"), R_FIELD = c("Gender", "Age", 
"Activation", "WakeUpStroke", "ArMode", "PreHospActiv", "EMTag", 
"EMTdx", "EMTlams")), .Names = c("Var_Typer", "R_FIELD"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")

    > head(A)
  Var_Typer      R_FIELD
1       cnt       Gender
2      Cont          Age
3       cnt   Activation
4       cnt WakeUpStroke
5      fact       ArMode
6      fact PreHospActiv



 B <- apply(
       dcast(A, Var_Typer ~ R_FIELD, value.var = 'R_FIELD'), 1, function(i){
         ndf <- as.data.frame(rbind(i[complete.cases(i)]))
         colnames(ndf) <- c('Class',1:(length(ndf)-1))
         ndf
       }) %>% rbind.pages %>% (function(x){
              x[is.na(x)] <- "..."
              x
            })


   Class          1            2            3
 1  Char      EMTag        EMTdx          ...
 2   cnt Activation       Gender WakeUpStroke
 3  Cont        Age      EMTlams          ...
 4  fact     ArMode PreHospActiv          ...
```

Comment: For brevity @docween I'd like to point out that this is a fairly useless way to structure this data.